# Can actors read messages under a certain condition?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor, message

I have this situation:

- ActorA sends ActorB start/stop messages every 30-40 seconds
- ActorA sends ActorB strings to print (always)
- ActorB must print the strings he receive, but only if ActorA sent just a start message

Now i wonder if i can do the following things:

- Can ActorB read messages only under a certain condition (if a boolean is set as true) without losing the messages he receives while that boolean is set as false?
- Can ActorB read a start/stop message from ActorA before the other string messages? I'd like to have this situation: ActorA sends a start message to ActorB, ActorB start printing the strings he received before the start messages (and that is still receiving) and then stop as soon as it receives a stop messages?

I don't know if I explained it well.

EDIT: Thank you, the answers are great, but I still have some doubts.

- Does the become mantain the order of the messages? I mean, if i have "Start-M1-M2-Stop-M3-M4-M5-Start-M6-M7-Stop", will the printing order be "M1-M2" and then "M3-M4-M5-M6-M7" or could M6 be read before M3, M4 and M5 (if M6 is received just after the become)?
- Can I give a higher priority to start/stop messages? If ActorB receives "M1-M2-M3", and then it receives a stop message while it is printing "M1", i want that ActorB saves again M2 and M3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exactly solve your problem with the `Stash` trait and the `become/unbecome` functionality of Akka. The idea is the following:

When you receive a `Stop` message then you switch to a behaviour where you stash all messages which are not `Start`. When you receive a `Start` message, then you switch to a behaviour where you print all received messages and additionally you unstash all messages which have arrived in the meantime.

```scala
case object Start
case object Stop
case object TriggerStateChange
case object SendMessage

class ActorB extends Actor with Stash {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Start =>
      context.become(printingBehavior, false)
      unstashAll()
    case x => stash()
  }

  def printingBehavior: Receive = {
    case msg: String => println(msg)
    case Stop => context.unbecome()
  }
}

class ActorA(val actorB: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  var counter = 0
  var started = false

  override def preStart: Unit = {
    import context.dispatcher

    this.context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 seconds, self, TriggerStateChange)
    this.context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 seconds, self, SendMessage)
  }

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case SendMessage =>
      actorB ! "Message: " + counter
      counter += 1
    case TriggerStateChange =>
      actorB ! (if (started) {
        started = false
        Stop
      } else {
        started = true
        Start
      })
  }
}

object Akka {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val system = ActorSystem.create("TestActorSystem")

    val actorB = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ActorB]), "ActorB")
    val actorA = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ActorA], actorB), "ActorA")

    system.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the `unstashAll()` mantain the order of the message? I mean, if i have "Start-M1-M2-Stop-M3-M4-M5-Start-M6-M7-Stop", will the printing order be "M1-M2-M3-M4-M5-M6-M7" or could M6 be read before M3, M4 and M5 (if M6 is received just after the `unstashAll()`)?

Comment: @AsAs, internally the `unstashAll()` method calls `enqueueFirst` on the mailbox. Therefore, I assume that you'll first receive your unstashed messages in the order they were stashed and then any messages which have been received while or after the `unstashAll()` call.

Comment: Thank you. Another thing. Can I give a higher priority to start/stop messages? If ActorB receives "Start-M1-M2-M3", and then it receives a stop message while it is printing "M1", i want that ActorB saves again M2 and M3. Is it possible?

Comment: At the moment I think there is no priority mailbox which also supports the required dequeue behaviour for the `Stash`. I guess that has to still to be implemented.

Comment: Do you think i can do that thing with just a priority mailbox then? I was thinking that i could use start/stop messages with max priority and string messages with min priority. When i receive a start message, i could use `become` and then send me again all the messages with medium priority. This way i'll receive them in the other `receive` and the old messages will be read before the most recent messages.

Comment: Does a priority mailbox mantain the order of the messages with the same priority in the first place?

Comment: @AsAs, your idea of sending all the message to yourself directly after `become` won't assure that you'll receive these messages at first. The reason is that you have two different sender, yourself and the remote sender. Between those senders there is no guarantee for an ordering of the messages. Concerning your second question, I think it depends on the `Comparator` you provide. But in general they can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Become/Unbecome](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome) functionality. It lets you change the behavior of the actor.

If I understood correctly you want your ActorB to have two different states. In the first state it should cache the messages it receives. In the second state, it should print all the cached messages and start printing all the new ones.

Something like this:

```
case class Start
case class Stop
case class Message(val: String)

class ActorB extends Actor {

  var cache = Queue()

  def initial: Receive = {
    case Message(msg) => cache += msg
    case Start => 
      for (m <- cache) self ! Message(m)
      context.become(printing)
  }

  def printing: Receive = {
    case Message(msg) => println(msg)
    case Stop => context.become(initial) //or stop the actor
  }

  def receive = initial
}
```

Comment: 1) Shouldn't the `for` line come after the `become` line?

2) Does the `become` mantain the order of the message? I mean, if i have "Start-M1-M2-Stop-M3-M4-M5-Start-M6-M7-Stop", will the printing order be "M1-M2-M3-M4-M5-M6-M7" or could M6 be read before M3, M4 and M5 (if it is received just after the `become`)?

Answer (score 0):

Have Actor B alternate between two states (two different behaviours). In the initial 'pending' state, it waits for a 'start' message, while [stashing](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.Stash) any other messages.

On receipt of a 'start' message, unstash all the stored messages and [become](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actor-hotswap) 'active', waiting on a 'stop' message and writing out the other messages received (which will include the unstashed ones). On receiveing a 'stop' message, revert to the 'pending' behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Some of my thoughts

1. Yes if the boolean flag is got from some system resource like db or a config file, but I don't think it should be dependent on any external message, given that the actor receive messages from multiple other actors. If ActorB is only used by ActorA, the two can be merged to one
2. Similar as 1, how to handle the messages from multiple actors? If there is only one actorA, the two actors can be merged. If there are multiple, the flag can be set in database, actorA change the flag in db to "Start" or "Stop". and Actor B will print or not based on the flag.

An actor should be doing something very independently on other actor's state. The start and stop is actually some state of ActorA instead of ActorB

Answer (score 0):

You already have a lot of good answers, but somehow I feel compelled to offer something more brief, as what you need is not necessarily a state machine:

```
class ActorB extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = caching(Nil)

  def caching(cached: List[String]): Receive = {
    case msg: String => 
      context.become(caching(msg :: cached))
    case Start => 
      cached.reverse.foreach(println)
      context.become(caching(Nil))
  }
}
```