# Akka priority mailbox and stash/unstash

Tags: scala, akka, actor, message

I have this situation:

- `ActorA` sends `ActorB` start/stop messages every 30-40 seconds
- `ActorA` sends `ActorB` strings to print (always)
- `ActorB` must print the strings he receives, but only if `ActorA` sent just a start message

My code :

```
case object Start
case object Stop
case object TriggerStateChange
case object SendMessage

class ActorB extends Actor with Stash {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Start =>
      context.become(printingBehavior, false)
      unstashAll()
    case x => stash()
  }

  def printingBehavior: Receive = {
    case msg: String => println(msg)
    case Stop => context.unbecome()
  }
}

class ActorA(val actorB: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  var counter = 0
  var started = false

  override def preStart: Unit = {
    import context.dispatcher

    this.context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 seconds, self, TriggerStateChange)
    this.context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 seconds, self, SendMessage)
  }

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case SendMessage =>
      actorB ! "Message: " + counter
      counter += 1
    case TriggerStateChange =>
      actorB ! (if (started) {
        started = false
        Stop
      } else {
        started = true
        Start
      })
  }
}

object Akka {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val system = ActorSystem.create("TestActorSystem")

    val actorB = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ActorB]), "ActorB")
    val actorA = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ActorA], actorB), "ActorA")

    system.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I used this code [suggested by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273549/can-actors-read-messages-under-a-certain-condition), but I have a problem. 
`ActorB` should stop as soon as it receives a stop message (so if it receives M1-M2-M3 and a stop message while printing M1, it must not print M2 and M3 yet). I thought to use a priority mailbox, but `stash()` and `unstash()` don't work with priority mailboxes yet. Is there a way to do this just with a priority mailbox?

And if I have the sequence M1-M2-M3-Stop-M4-Start-M5 (and stop received while printing M1), I should get a first print "M1" and a second one "M2-M3-M4-M5" (so the old M2 and M3 must be printed before the new M4). `Stash()` and `unstash()` don't work with priority mailbox, so my idea was to create start/stop messages with max priority, M1, M2, etc... messages with min priority, and after I use `become()`, I though that `ActorB` could send again the saved messages, but this time with medium priority (so they'll be read before new messages, but after stop messages). Is it possible? Is there a better solution?

Comment: This situation will never occur with a sender-receiver pair as you have described in this scenario. Akka explicitly guarantees this: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html

Comment: So if i have a priority mailbox, the order of the messages may change even if they have the same priority?

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood your post, it does seem like a priority mailbox would accomplish what you are suggesting. If stash and unstash don't work, you could just use a queue.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to introduce new `ActorC` it could be solved like that:

- `ActorA` sends messages to print and Start/Stop messages to `ActorC`
- `ActorB` sends a message to `ActorC` when it is ready to print
- If `ActorC` got Start message from `ActorA` earlier then it sends next message to print to `ActorB`. Else it just waits for Start message and sends nothing to `ActorB`.

This way if M1-M2-M3-Stop sequence comes while `ActorB` is still printing M1, no messages will be printed until next Start message.